# Using jQuery “each” to style tree

Tags: jquery, css, arrays, foreach, each

I'm using this code to style an elements tree:

```
 $('.js-toprow').each(function(index) {
        if (index % 2 === 0) { // Even
          $(this).css('background', '#ddd');
        } else { // Odd
          $(this).css('background', '#ff0000');
        }        
    });
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is that I need one element to be even and one to be odd.
It works just fine, except for the fact that around the element 4 or 5, the two last elements are getting the same color. take a look at the screenshots.

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/865ytmkd/35/

Looks like the slide show code moves elements around which is probably where the issue lies.

Full code:

```
jQuery(function ($) {

$("#jobshome").load("jobs/newest-jobs .js-toprow", function(){
    //rotation speed and timer
    var speed = 4000;
    var run = setInterval(rotate, speed);
    var slides = $('.js-toprow');
    var container = $('#jobshome');
    var elm = container.children(':first-child').prop("tagName");
    var item_height = container.height();
    var previous = 'prevabc'; //id of previous button
    var next = 'nextabc'; //id of next button
    slides.height(item_height); //set the slides to the correct pixel height
    container.parent().height(item_height);
    container.height(slides.length * item_height); //set the slides container to the correct total height
    container.children(elm + ':first').before(container.children(elm + ':last'));
    resetSlides(); 


    //if user clicked on prev button

    $('#buttonsabc a').click(function (e) {
        //slide the item

        if (container.is(':animated')) {
            return false;
        }
        if (e.target.id == previous) {
            container.stop().animate({
                'top': 0
            }, 1000, function () {
                container.children(elm + ':first').before(container.children(elm + ':last'));
                resetSlides();
            });
        }

        if (e.target.id == next) {
            container.stop().animate({
                'top': item_height * -2
            }, 1000, function () {
                container.children(elm + ':last').after(container.children(elm + ':first'));
                resetSlides();
            }
      );
    }
        //cancel the link behavior            
        return false;

    });

    //if mouse hover, pause the auto rotation, otherwise rotate it    
    container.parent().mouseenter(function () {
        clearInterval(run);
    }).mouseleave(function () {
        run = setInterval(rotate, speed);
    });


    function resetSlides() {
        //and adjust the container so current is in the frame
        container.css({
            'top': -1 * item_height
        });
    }


$('.js-toprow').each(function(index) {
    if (index % 2 === 0) { // Even
      $(this).css('background', '#f4f5f7');
    } else { // Odd
      $(this).css('background', '#ffffff');
    }  

});


});
//a simple function to click next link
//a timer will call this function, and the rotation will begin

function rotate() {
    jQuery('#nextabc').click();
}

});
```

1
[image: Elements with different colors,you may need to adjust your screen brightness]

2
[image: Elements with the same color, The problem]

3
[image: The tree showing the elements with the same color]

Another screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnhHM.jpg

Comment: i'd use a css nth selector.

Comment: also each's callback has the element as the first one.

Comment: I tried using a nth selector, but I failed.

Comment: Yeah, css nth-selector might be a better solution than having a script run to add inline style. `.js-toprow:nth-child(odd) { background: #fff }` and `.js-toprow:nth-child(even) { background: #ddd }`

Answer (score 1):

CSS will be better and easy solution, still if you want to stick with this code then the problem is in if condition..
replace the index in if condition with (index + 1)

```
$('.js-toprow').each(function(index) {
        if ((index+1) % 2 === 0) { // Even
          $(this).css('background', '#ddd');
        } else { // Odd
          $(this).css('background', '#ff0000');
        }        
    });
```

Here is a CSS solution.

```
#jobshome > div:nth-child(even) {background: #f4f5f7}
#jobshome > div:nth-child(odd) {background: #CCC}
```

**Update 1:**

I am updating the answer to remove the code which rotates the slide div from first to last element. Find commented line (REMOVING THIS LINE).

```js
jQuery(function ($) {

$("#jobshome").load(".js-toprow", function(){
    //rotation speed and timer
    var speed = 4000;
    var run = setInterval(rotate, speed);
    var slides = $('.js-toprow');
    var container = $('#jobshome');
    var elm = container.children(':first-child').prop("tagName");
    var item_height = container.height();
    var previous = 'prevabc'; //id of previous button
    var next = 'nextabc'; //id of next button
    slides.height(item_height); //set the slides to the correct pixel height
    container.parent().height(item_height);
    container.height(slides.length * item_height); //set the slides container to the correct total height
    container.children(elm + ':first').before(container.children(elm + ':last'));
    resetSlides(); 
    
    
    //if user clicked on prev button
    
    $('#buttonsabc a').click(function (e) {
        //slide the item
        
        if (container.is(':animated')) {
            return false;
        }
        if (e.target.id == previous) {
            container.stop().animate({
                'top': 0
            }, 1000, function () {
               // container.children(elm + ':first').before(container.children(elm + ':last'));REMOVING THIS LINE.
                resetSlides();
            });
        }
        
        if (e.target.id == next) {
            container.stop().animate({
                'top': item_height * -2
            }, 1000, function () {
                //container.children(elm + ':last').after(container.children(elm + ':first')); REMOVING THIS LINE.
                resetSlides();
            }
      );
    }
        //cancel the link behavior            
        return false;
        
    });
    
    //if mouse hover, pause the auto rotation, otherwise rotate it    
    container.parent().mouseenter(function () {
        clearInterval(run);
    }).mouseleave(function () {
        run = setInterval(rotate, speed);
    });
    
    
    function resetSlides() {
        //and adjust the container so current is in the frame
        container.css({
            'top': -1 * item_height
        });
    }

    
$('.js-toprow').each(function(index) {
        if ((index+1) % 2 === 0) { // Even
          $(this).css('background', '#ddd');
        } else { // Odd
          $(this).css('background', '#ff0000');
        }        
    });

 
});
//a simple function to click next link
//a timer will call this function, and the rotation will begin

function rotate() {
    jQuery('#nextabc').click();
}

});
```

```css
#carouselabc {
position: relative;
width:100%;
margin:0 auto;
}

#slidesabc {
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height:220px;
}

#areadoslideabc {
list-style: none;
width:100%;
height:220px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
}

 #slidesabcdef {
width:100%;
height:220px;
float:left;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
font-family:lato, sans-serif;
}
/* Styling for prev and next buttons */
.btn-barabc{
    /* margin: 0 auto 0 auto; */
    /* display: table; */
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
 #buttonsabc {
 display: flex;  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;     position: relative;
 }

#buttonsabc a {
text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
 font-weight:bolder;
    outline: 0;
    margin: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: table;
    color: #cb2027;
    border-radius: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 100%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
    border: solid 0.2rem #385778;
    background: #ffffff;
}
a#prevabc, a#nextabc { display:table }
a#prevabc:hover, a#nextabc:hover {
color:#000;
text-shadow:.5px 0px #b14943;  
}




#wrapper {height:220px;  margin:0; padding:0 }




@media screen and (max-width: 849px) {
.latestjobs #jobshome {
text-align:center }
.latestjobs .js-image { display: table; float: none; width:40%; margin:auto; padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px;}
.latestjobs .js-data { display: table; width: 100%;}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 850px) {
.latestjobs #jobshome { 
text-align:left}
.latestjobs .js-image { display: table; float: left; width: 30%;     padding: 10px 10px 0 5px;}
.latestjobs .js-data { display: table; width: 69%;}
}
 
.latestjobs { border: 1px solid #E3E3E3 ; text-align: center !important; clear:both !important;  background-color: #efefef;

}
.latestjobs #jobshome {
width:100%; height:220px;
padding: 0;
margin:0;  position:relative}
.latestjobs .js-toprow { overflow: inherit; height:inherit;   padding: 10px 0 10px 0;}
/*.latestjobs .js-toprow:nth-child(even) { background: #efefef; }
.latestjobs .js-toprow:nth-child(odd) { background:#fbfbfb; }*/


.latestjobs  .js-bold, .js-type, .js-bold { font-weight:bolder; color: #000;}

.latestjobs a.jobtitle { padding-right: 15px; }
.latestjobs span.js-type {  display: table; float: right;   padding: 4px;  margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px; border: solid thin;  display: table;  padding-left: 10px; }
.latestjobs span.js-type{ background:transparent}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">



<div class="moduletable latestjobs">
       <h3 class="g-title">Latest jobs</h3>
      

<div class="customlatestjobs">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/go/scripts/jqueryautoscroll/autoscroll.css">

<!-- Auto Scroll -->
<script src="/go/scripts/jqueryautoscroll/autoscroll.js"></script>


<div id="carouselabc">
    <div id="slidesabc" style="height: 220px;">
<div id="jobshome" style="height: 1100px; top: -220px;"><div class="js-toprow" style="height: 240px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><div class="js-image"><a href="/jobs/company-detail/company-1/nav-31"><img src="https://fleamerica.com/jsjobsdata/data/employer/comp_1/logo/logo-for-hotlinking_important[1].png" title="FleAmerica Jobs"></a></div><div class="js-data"><div class="js-first-row"><span class="js-col-xs-12 js-col-md-6 js-title js-title-tablet"> <a class="jobtitle" href="/jobs/job-detail/job-accountant-3">Accountant</a></span><span class="js-col-xs-12 js-col-md-6 js-jobtype js-jobtype-tablet">Posted: 782 Days Ago<span class="js-type">Full-Time</span></span></div><div class="js-second-row"><div class="js-col-xs-12 js-col-md-5 js-fields"><span class="js-bold">Job Category: </span>Computer/IT</div><div class="js-col-xs-12 js-col-md-5 js-fields"><span class="js-bold">Job Salary Range: </span>$ 4000 - 4500 Per Month</div><div class="js-col-xs-12 js-col-md-2 js-fields no-padding"> <span class="js-totaljobs">1 Jobs</span></div></div>
                            </div>
                        </div><div class="js-toprow" style="height: 240px; background: rgb(244, 245, 247);"><div class="js-image"><a href="/jobs/company-detail/company-1/nav-31"><img src="https://fleamerica.com/jsjobsdata/data/employer/comp_1/logo/logo-for-hotlinking_important[1].png" title="FleAmerica Jobs"></a></div><div class="js-data"><div class="js-first-row"><span class="js-col-xs-12 js-col-md-6 js-title js-title-tablet"> <a class="jobtitle" href="/jobs/job-detail/job-senior-software-engineer-4">Senior Software Engineer</a></span><span class="js-col-xs-12 js-col-md-6 js-jobtype js-jobtype-tablet">Posted: 782 Days Ago<span class="js-type">Full-Time</span></span></div><div class="js-second-row"><div class="js-col-xs-12 js-col-md-5 js-fields"><span class="js-bold">Job Category: </span>Computer/IT</div><div class="js-col-xs-12 js-col-md-5 js-fields"><span class="js-bold">Job Salary Range: </span>$ 4500 - 5000 Per Month</div><div class="js-col-xs-12 js-col-md-2 js-fields no-padding"> <span class="js-totaljobs">1 Jobs</span></div></div>
                            </div>
                        </div><div class="js-toprow" style="height: 240px; background: rgb(244, 245, 247);"><div class="js-image"><a href="/jobs/company-detail/company-1/nav-31"><img src="https://fleamerica.com/jsjobsdata/data/employer/comp_1/logo/logo-for-hotlinking_important[1].png" title="FleAmerica Jobs"></a></div><div class="js-data"><div class="js-first-row"><span class="js-col-xs-12 js-col-md-6 js-title js-title-tablet"> <a class="jobtitle" href="/jobs/job-detail/job-web-designer-5">Web Designer</a></span><span class="js-col-xs-12 js-col-md-6 js-jobtype js-jobtype-tablet">Posted: 782 Days Ago<span class="js-type">Full-Time</span></span></div><div class="js-second-row"><div class="js-col-xs-12 js-col-md-5 js-fields"><span class="js-bold">Job Category: </span>Computer/IT</div><div class="js-col-xs-12 js-col-md-5 js-fields"><span class="js-bold">Job Salary Range: </span>$ 1000 - 1500 Per Month</div><div class="js-col-xs-12 js-col-md-2 js-fields no-padding"> <span class="js-totaljobs">1 Jobs</span></div></div>
                            </div>
                        </div><div class="js-toprow" style="height: 240px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><div class="js-image"><a href="/jobs/company-detail/company-1/nav-31"><img src="https://fleamerica.com/jsjobsdata/data/employer/comp_1/logo/logo-for-hotlinking_important[1].png" title="FleAmerica Jobs"></a></div><div class="js-data"><div class="js-first-row"><span class="js-col-xs-12 js-col-md-6 js-title js-title-tablet"> <a class="jobtitle" href="/jobs/job-detail/job-php-developer-1">PHP Developer</a></span><span class="js-col-xs-12 js-col-md-6 js-jobtype js-jobtype-tablet">Posted: 782 Days Ago<span class="js-type">Full-Time</span></span></div><div class="js-second-row"><div class="js-col-xs-12 js-col-md-5 js-fields"><span class="js-bold">Job Category: </span>Computer/IT</div><div class="js-col-xs-12 js-col-md-5 js-fields"><span class="js-bold">Job Salary Range: </span>$ 1000 - 1500 Per Month</div><div class="js-col-xs-12 js-col-md-2 js-fields no-padding"> <span class="js-totaljobs">2 Jobs</span></div></div>
                            </div>
                        </div><div class="js-toprow" style="height: 240px; background: rgb(244, 245, 247);"><div class="js-image"><a href="/jobs/company-detail/company-1/nav-31"><img src="https://fleamerica.com/jsjobsdata/data/employer/comp_1/logo/logo-for-hotlinking_important[1].png" title="FleAmerica Jobs"></a></div><div class="js-data"><div class="js-first-row"><span class="js-col-xs-12 js-col-md-6 js-title js-title-tablet"> <a class="jobtitle" href="/jobs/job-detail/job-games-developer-2">Android Developer</a></span><span class="js-col-xs-12 js-col-md-6 js-jobtype js-jobtype-tablet">Posted: 782 Days Ago<span class="js-type">Full-Time</span></span></div><div class="js-second-row"><div class="js-col-xs-12 js-col-md-5 js-fields"><span class="js-bold">Job Category: </span>Computer/IT</div><div class="js-col-xs-12 js-col-md-5 js-fields"><span class="js-bold">Job Salary Range: </span>$ 2500 - 3000 Per Month</div><div class="js-col-xs-12 js-col-md-2 js-fields no-padding"> <span class="js-totaljobs">3 Jobs</span></div></div>
                            </div>
                        </div></div>
</div>
  <div class="btn-barabc">
    <div id="buttonsabc">    <a id="prevabc" href="#">&lt; &lt;</a><a id="nextabc" href="#">&gt; &gt;</a> 
  </div></div>
</div>



<!--   Source:https://codepen.io/TyStelmach/pen/yygvNK
<script>//jQuery("#jobshome").load("jobs/newest-jobs .js-toprow"); </script>
 --></div>
  </div>  </div>
```

Comment: CSS isn't a better solution in this case, but I agree with you on overall. The first thing I tried using was CSS, but the jQuery is reseting the elements positions, thus making pure css useless.

Comment: @Matt choise is yours :) both solutions are there

Comment: Oh I know why.. I think its because library is changing the div from first to last. When it scrolls, it is adding first div to last. And you have 5 divs, that's why its working for first time..

Comment: You can remove these two lines.. container.children(elm + ':first').before(container.children(elm + ':last'));.. Its workinf fine now. https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/865ytmkd/44/

Comment: Did you change anything besides the javascript?

Comment: If this is fixing your problem, then can you please accept my solution? ;)

Comment: If it fixes the problem I'll. Run the snippet and see what's happening.